# Angular Lazy Loading events for start/end loading

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

Is there any events when ngModule starts/ends lazy loaded?
I would need one of this events to also load some additional resources like translates.

It would be also nice to display some animation, so user knows something is loading when it clicks for the first time on LazyLoaded route.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are two events [RouteConfigLoadStart](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteConfigLoadStart) and [RouteConfigLoadEnd](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteConfigLoadEnd) that you can use like this:

```
constructor(router:Router) {
  router.events.subscribe(event:Event => {
    if(event instanceof RouteConfigLoadStart) {
    }
    if(event instanceof RouteConfigLoadEnd) {
    }
  });
}
```